Custom Sound for notifications is not playing
I am using FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin to display local notifications with a custom sound in my Flutter app. The sound file (notification.mp3) is placed in the android/app/src/main/res/raw directory, and I am referencing it using RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification'). Despite this setup, the custom sound does not play, and the app logs indicate that the sound file is not found.

Notification Channel Initialization:

static Future initLocalNotification({bool isScheduled = false}) async {

    final androidInit = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    final iosInit = DarwinInitializationSettings();
    final initSetting =
        InitializationSettings(android: androidInit, iOS: iosInit);

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetting);
    log("inside initlocalNotification");
    // Define default notification channels with custom sound
    AndroidNotificationChannel orderReceiveChannel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'order_received',
      'Order Notification Channel',
      description: 'Order Notification Channel',
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      playSound: true,
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(
          'notification'), // Custom sound for Android
    );

    const AndroidNotificationChannel otherNotificationChannel =
        AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'other_notification',
      'Other Notification Channel',
      description: 'Other Notification Channel',
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      playSound: true,
    );

    // Register the channels for Android
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(orderReceiveChannel);
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(otherNotificationChannel);
  }



Notification Listener:

listenNotification() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {

      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      log("inside listenNotification");
      print("inside listenNotification");

      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        log('Using "${message.data['channelId']}" channel for notification');
        AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
          message.data['channelId'] ?? 'other_notification',
          message.data['channelId'] == 'order_received'
              ? 'Order Notification Channel'
              : 'Other Notification Channel',
          playSound: true,
          sound: message.data['channelId'] == 'order_received'
              ? RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification')
              : null,
          priority: Priority.max,
        );

        // iOS notification details with custom sound
        DarwinNotificationDetails iosDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails(
          sound: message.data['channelId'] == 'order_received'
              ? 'notification.wav'
              : null, // Custom sound for iOS
        );

        // Combine Android and iOS details
        NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
          android: androidDetails,
          iOS: iosDetails,
        );

        // Show the notification
        _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          notificationDetails,
        );
      }
    });
  }


Sound File Validation:

void validateSoundFile() {
  String soundFilePath = 'android/app/src/main/res/raw/notification.mp3';
  File soundFile = File(soundFilePath);

  if (!soundFile.existsSync()) {
    log('❌ ERROR: No sound file found at $soundFilePath');
  }
}

What I Have Tried:

Ensured the notification.mp3 file exists in android/app/src/main/res/raw.
Created the notification channel with playSound: true and provided the correct sound reference.
Used validateSoundFile to check if the file exists at runtime, which logs that the file is not found.
Reinstalled the app to clear any caching issues.

Issue: Despite the sound file being in the correct location, it is not detected or played during the notification. The log consistently shows "No sound file found."
Request for Help:

How can I ensure the custom sound file is detected and played correctly?
Is there any specific step I am missing in configuring the custom sound for local notifications on Android?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
